# Python Estimate the standard deviation after data fitting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, standard-deviation, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a data set into the hyperpolic equation using ipython --pylab:
y = ax / (b + x)

### Here is my python code:

```
from scipy import optimize as opti
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

x = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8])
y = np.array([0.375, 0.466, 0.509, 0.520, 0.525, 0.536, 0.541])
y_stdev = np.array([0.025, 0.016, 0.009, 0.009, 0.025, 0.019])

def func(x, a, b):
   return a*x / (b + x)

popt, pcov = opti.curve_fit(func, x, y)
print(popt)
print("a = ", popt.ix[0])
print("b = ", popt.ix[1])
```

The values of **a** and **b** should be inside the popt parameter. What I would like to ask is, the values of **a** and **b** are inferred when fitting the data set into the func(x, a, b), then, **how can we estimate the standard deviations of a and b?**
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> **pcov** : 2d array
>
> The estimated covariance of popt. The diagonals provide the variance of the parameter estimate. To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use `perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`...

Comment: Thank you for your help, Foglerit. I should have read more carefully the [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) before.